# Update associated records when master table record is updated

Tags: ms-access

I'm relatively new to MS access and am seeking some assistance.

I have a programs table (tblPrograms) and a history table (tblLog).

On my edit program form (frmEditProgram) I want all historical records (tblLog) to update based on this change.

Example:

- I have a program called "Cleaning".
- I open the Edit Program form, and change the record to be "Cleaning - Level 1"
- I want all records in tblLog that WERE "cleaning" to be updated to "cleaning - level 1"

I understand this is probably extremely basic I'm just having difficulty putting this solution into a googleable question.

I can't express how grateful I would be for any help!

I'm lost as to where to start outside creating an update query, but I'm unsure the correct way to direct this.

N/A

n/a

Comment: Sounds like a fairly simple UPDATE action. Why would you want to change historical records? Then they are no longer historical, they have current data.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Cascade Update](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-dfa453a7-0b6d-4c34-a128-fdebc7e686af#__bmcascade), but you should neither need nor do this here.

You should **normalize** your tables.

- Link your tables with an internal ID (`Autonumber` primary key in Program, `Long` foreign key in Log).
- tblLog must not have a column "Program name", since this is duplicating information
- When createing a log list with program names, use a query that joins both tables. Program name is retrieved from tblLog.